# Drupal - updating content type with new fields doesn't update existing content

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Quick question I think...

I've made a drupal site which has some custom content types. I've created a load of records with these, and then I've had to amend the custom content type to change one of the fields and give it a new default value.

The problem is that existing records do not update with this default value. Apparently i've got to go and re-edit everything to add the default value.

NEW records have the default value. No problem there.

Is this just a Drupal thing or am I missing a trick?

Thanks, 
Hugh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is a 'Drupal thing' (more precisely, a CCK thing ;)

I stumbled over this problem once and as far as I recall, found no logic in CCK to apply changes retroactively to existing nodes. So you'll need to ensure a load/save cycle for every affected node by some means. For small amounts, this might be done via one or the other bulk operation on 'admin/content/node/overview'. For bigger amounts of nodes, this might call for a little script calling `node_load()`, `node_save()` on all affected nodes.

Comment: Hi Henrik, yeah I feared that would be the case! Thanks for the tip, I'll have a look into scripting it all.

Answer (score 1):

Posting for anyone in the future:
https://www.drupal.org/project/field_defaults

Allows you to update existing content when creating a field or editing defaults on an existing field

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

using sql , considering that nodes with the field value not set are

```
SELECT nid,vid
 from node where type='procedure' and nid not in (select entity_id from field_data_field_pr_choix_du_document)
```

field_data_field_pr_choix_du_document being the table corresponding to my field and containing one entry par value set with entity id referinng the node

i did using SQL insert...select syntax

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html

```
INSERT INTO `field_data_field_pr_choix_du_document` (`entity_type`, `bundle`, `deleted`, `entity_id`, `revision_id`, `language`, `delta`, `field_pr_choix_du_document_value`)
SELECT 'node','procedure',0,nid,vid,'und',0,'Importer un document'
from node where type='procedure' and nid not in (select entity_id from field_data_field_pr_choix_du_document)
```